Any movie clip does not get removed after the video player completes playing the video format in my AS2 project
class StoryMode extends SystemVideoPlayer
{
    var _timeline;
    var ns;
    var nc;
    var _borderLeft;
    var _borderRight;
    static var instance;
    var isVideoComplete = false;
    function StoryMode()
    {
        super.init();
        this.buildVideoPlayer();
    }
    static function getInstance()
    {
        if (StoryMode.instance == null || StoryMode.instance == undefined)
        {
            StoryMode.instance = new StoryMode();
        }
        return StoryMode.instance;
    }
    function buildVideoPlayer()
    {
        super.updateDisplay();
        this.videoWrapper = _root.attachMovie("VideoWrapper", "videoWrapper", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this._borderLeft = _root.attachMovie("borderLeft", "_borderLeft", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this._borderLeft._x = 0;
        this._borderLeft._y = 0;
        this._borderRight = _root.attachMovie("borderRight", "_borderRight", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
        this._borderRight._x = 747;
        this._borderRight._y = 0;
        this.videoInstance = Video(this.videoWrapper.getInstanceByName("video1"));
        this.resizeVideoPlayer(640,480);
        this.rePositionVideoPlayer(107,0);
        this.nc = new NetConnection();
        this.nc.connect(null);
        this.ns = new NetStream(this.nc);
        this.videoInstance.attachVideo(this.ns);
        this.ns.onStatus = function(info:Object):Void 
        {
            if (info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop")
            {
                StoryMode.getInstance().destroyVideoPlayer();
                StoryMode.getInstance().isVideoComplete = true;
            }
        };
        this.ns.play("story.flv");
    }
    function destroyVideoPlayer()
    {
        if (this.ns != null)
        {
            this.ns.close();
        }
        if (this.videoInstance != null)
        {
            this._borderLeft._visible = false;
            this._borderRight._visible = false;
            _root.videoInstance.clear();
        }
        _root.videoWrapper.removeMovieClip();
    }
}

Greetings, I'm still working on that same project, but this time the video player. For some reason, after the video is complete, only either the video instance or the video wrapper gets cleared, not any other movie clips that have been attached such as the borders.
I tried doing this:
if(this.border != null)
{
   this.border.removeMovieClip();
}

but that doesn't work.
these does not work either:
if(this.border != null)
{
   this.border._visible = false;
}

function destroyVideoPlayer()
    {
        if (this.ns != null)
        {
            this.ns.close();
        }
        if (this.videoInstance != null)
        {
            this._borderLeft._visible = false;
            this._borderRight._visible = false;
            _root.videoInstance.clear();
        }
        _root.videoWrapper.removeMovieClip();
    }

    function destroyVideoPlayer()
    {
        if (this.ns != null)
        {
            this.ns.close();
        }
        if (this.videoInstance != null)
        {
            _root.videoInstance.clear();
        }
               _root.borderLeft.removeMovieClip();
               _root.borderRight.removeMovieClip();
        _root.videoWrapper.removeMovieClip();
    }

function destroyVideoPlayer()
    {
        if (this.ns != null)
        {
            this.ns.close();
        }
        if (this.videoInstance != null)
        {
            _root.videoInstance.clear();
        }
        _root.videoWrapper.removeMovieClip();
        if (_root.borderLeft != null)
        {
            _root.borderLeft.removeMovieClip();
        }
        if (_root.borderRight != null)
        {
            _root.borderRight.removeMovieClip();
        }
    }

All I want is for any other movie clip to get removed after the video is complete playing.

My AS2 is really rusty, but I think the general problem is about where this points at the moment (spoiler alert: it is not always the context of current instance) and if you actually can address the _root. My advice: create a contained with createEmptyMovieClip(...), place it at fixed non-negative depth, like 1, then attach everything INTO it, then you only need to remove it while everything inside it goes away with it.
